# DetectChanges when using AspNet.Identity UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, savechanges

I am using `AspNet.Identity` for User Management in my MVC project because I believe it is a great start, now that I have it working (with little changes), I wanted to add an Audit Trail (Track Changes) like my other DbContext that I use.

In `IdentityModel.cs`, I have the following code that works, but only in certain situations:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        //Can't recall if this was there by default
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //Tell EF to Track Changes
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        //More code once I get this working
        //
    }

}
```

In my Controller, I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel editUser)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);

    //Update a property within the User object
    user.FirstName = "Updated First Name";

    //Save to database
    var result = UserManager.Update(user);
    //The above saves to database, but doesn't trigger SaveChanges()

    //SaveChanges() will be triggered if I call
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();

}
```

When the above `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();` is called, the updated ApplicationUser has an `EntityState` of `Unchanged`.  Makes sense as it was already saved.

However, I am trying to see how I can utilize the `UserManager` and still work with `SaveChanges()`.

I also understand that I could write a class that would log all of this myself, but as I expand the ApplicationUser (or ApplicationRole) I would like to avoid the extra coding for the Audit Log.

Any advice or links would help!

Comment: google `Sql Trigger`

Comment: @Steve sorry, looking for a MVC solution with `DbContext` as my project is code first.

Comment: You can try with [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md) which is an extension for [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) to audit EF DbContext or ASP.NET IdentityContext.

Answer (score 1):

Set AutoSaveChanges to false in the constructor of your UserStore (which you would pass to the constructor of the UserManager).

```cs
public class MyUserStore : UserStore<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {
        private MyDbContext _context;
        public MyUserStore(MyDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            //Set this to false
            AutoSaveChanges = false;
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call save changes as you normally would and the change tracker will contain the changes you're expecting.

I did however encounter an OptimisticConcurrencyException when I tried to make more than one call to UserManager between calls to SaveChanges. I just called SaveChanges after each UserManager operation.